# Adding an image to a JTooltip without knowing the image's path (due to the image being a temporary ressource)

Tags: java, image, path, tooltip, temporary-files

To be a little more specific:
I've built a simple multithreaded TCPServer (Java) which communicates with clients (C# / mono). On request the Clients take a screenshot and send it to the Server.
The screenshots are then displayed in a JTable. I'd like to add a tooltip to these images in the table with the same image but in another size.
The code currently looks like this:

```
screenLabel.setToolTipText("<html><img src=\"" + (new ImageIcon(image)) + "\"></img> Tooltip</html>");
```

Of course, this won't work, as the  src  attribute requires a path.
The problem is, I don't know how to circumvent this behaviour.
My question would hence either be:
1) How to retrieve a valid path for a temporary resource (without saving the resource in the file-system)
OR
2) How to provide a custom JTooltip which easily allows Images/ImageIcons to be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add a new protocol besides the standard ftp/http/etc to the URL resolving which then maps into your own code instead of over the network.

There is three approaches listed at http://www.unicon.net/node/776, which may help you getting started.  I was thinking of extending URLStreamHandler and registering it with the JVM.

Regarding changing JToolTip, from http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=9915

"Remember JToolTip is a container, so ,
subclass JToolTip to have a JTextArea/Pane fill it . Set the JTA/JTP as
uneditable and voila you have a multiline tooltip! Similarly you can display
any custom component you want! "

Answer (score 0):

For option 2 you need to:

a) create a custom tooltip 
 
b) override the table to use the tooltip.

This [posting](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=57&threadID=5320538) provides a simple working example.